# I'm tryin to solve the problem "Length of Last Word" in leetcode. It showing runtime error but I got output for the same input in my machine

Tags: c

I'm getting error for the input "a".
Error message is like this
**=================================================================
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000008f at pc 0x55a501284db8 bp 0x7ffd0c0b9450 sp 0x7ffd0c0b9440
READ of size 1 at 0x60200000008f thread T0
#2 0x7f6a233ee082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082)
0x60200000008f is located 1 bytes to the left of 2-byte region [0x602000000090,0x602000000092)**

The code I have used is

```
int lengthOfLastWord(char *s){
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen(s) -1;
    int templen = len;
    for (int i = len;s[i] == ' ';i--){
        templen--;
    }
    for (int i = templen; (s[i] != ' ') && (i >= 0); i--){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Try it with an empty string where `len` becomes `-1`. What does `s[i]` do then?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried `for (int i = len;(s[i] == ' ') && (i >= 0);i--)` but still getting error

Comment: You effectively do `s[-1]` which makes your program have undefined behavior

Comment: please accept one of the answers, or explain how they do not solve your problem. If you do not know what the answers mean by "undefined behaviour", read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/7465516 . It is an important concept to know for any C-programmer.

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
for (int i = len;s[i] == ' ';i--){
    templen--;
}
```

causes "undefined behaviour" (possibly a crash) on input that consists only of spaces, since it doesn't stop at i==0.

Comment: An empty string would be bad too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have tried `for (int i = len;(s[i] == ' ') && (i >= 0);i--)` but still getting error

Comment: The check for range needs to be before you access the data. `if (in_range && value_matches)`

Comment: @RetiredNinja why I'm getting correct output in my local machine

Comment: It is undefined behavior to access the array out of bounds. One possible outcome of that is that it appears to work correctly. If you turn on AddressSanitizer it may catch the out of bounds access if it happens. Add `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile command if using gcc or clang.

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer to the problem (an illegal read of size 1 to the left of 2-byte-region matches this bug perfectly). Even if it does not fully solve the problem this answer found a bug in OPs code. So I really really do not understand the downvote.

Comment: @julaine the original answer stated "causes a crash", which is just one possible (though somewhat likely) outcome of "undefined behaviour". Maybe the downvote was deserved for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
(s[i] != ' ') && (i >= 0)
```

Due to the order of evaluation<sup>1</sup>, the access to the `i` element of the array is performed *before* the non negativity check, in a loop where the index is *decremented*. This results in undefined behavior<sup>2</sup> when `i` reaches -1 (access out of bounds) and one of the worst outcome of UB is IMHO a program seemingly producing the expected output.

To fix the code, we just have to check the indices *before* using them<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical#Logical_AND</sup> 
<sup>2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior</sup> 
<sup>3) https://godbolt.org/z/8oPeK64xq</sup>